# Jquery toggle accordion

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

Im trying to make an accordion with toggle which seems to work pretty good now. What i would like to get some help with as a newbie to javascript is the way it is put together.

http://jsfiddle.net/z3wW4/

This isnt pretty i know...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#contact').click(function() {
        $('#content2, #content3').hide(200, 'linear');
          $('#content').toggle(700, 'linear');          
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#services').click(function() {
        $('#content, #content3').hide(200, 'linear');
          $('#content2').toggle(700, 'linear');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#about').click(function() {
        $('#content, #content2').hide(200, 'linear');
          $('#content3').toggle(700, 'linear');
    });
});
```

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.
Your page doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
 $('#menu > a').click(function() { // specifies which a elements
     var that = $(this), // caching the selectors for performance
         divs = $(this).siblings('div'),
         div = $(this).nextAll('div:first');
     divs.not(div).hide(200, 'linear'); // hides all the sibling divs *except* for the
                                        // immediately following div element
     div.toggle(700, 'linear');         // toggles the immediately-following div
});
```

​
[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z3wW4/17/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

your code isn't very extensible, you might want to try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PzYvA/

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var $menu = $("#menu");
    $menu.children("a").click(function(){
        var $content = $(this).next("div");
        $menu.children("div").not($content).hide(200, 'linear');
        $content.toggle(700, 'linear');
    });
});
```

also add the following css

```
#menu > a {
    display:block;
}
```

and remove the `<br />` after the a tags

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... seems to be a problem when clicking the same link twice though.

Comment: @GustavHederström hmm, I don't see a problem in ff, what browser are you experiencing this in?

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your 3 fonctions have quite the same code.
Then, you have to use html class to define the functios of your html element, and then with javascript/jquery, defined how theses fonctions works.

It will simplify your CSS and your javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/td3UB/